# Xpages SSJS Time part of NotesDateTime does not return its real value

Tags: xpages

One of my date/Time filed value always return with 12:00:00. I have the same field with another document which always return with the correct value. 
I am trying to calculate timeDifferences of these two fields values. Because of this issue calculation always returns wrong. What did i miss?

```
var hdt1:NotesDateTime = doc.getItemValueDateTimeArray("Tarih").elementAt(0);
var hdt2:NotesDateTime = hhDoc.getItemValueDateTimeArray("Tarih").elementAt(0);
var frk:int=0;
print(hdt1);print(hdt2);print("------------------");
frk = hdt2.timeDifference(hdt1);
```

[image: Saved Value ScreenShot]
[image: Admin Panel print screen]

Comment: I think the "wrong" DtaeTime was saved with date value only. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_SETANYTIME_METHOD_JAVA.html

Comment: You could check if getting the datetime string via "doc.getItemValue("Tarih")[0].toJavaDate().toString()" leads to the same result. If so, I agree with Frantisek's assumption.

Answer (score 0):

```
doc.getFirstItem("Tarih").getDateTimeValue()
```